# Angular-Translate: Specify language per translated element

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using angular-translate to translate my Angular app.
This is working well so far.

Now I have the requirement to translate some parts of the page in another language than the rest of the page.

Specifically:

- The shell of the page (navigation, header etc) should be translated
  according to the language I have set with `$translate.use(lang).
- Some    content is only available in a specific language. Therefore
  the    section of the page that displays that content should be
  translated    to the language that matches the content.

Example:

```
<!--v this should be English -->
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong translate>ALERT</strong>
</div>
<!--^ this should be English -->

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <!--v this should be English -->
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title" translate>TITLE</h3>
    </div>
    <!--^ this should be English -->
    <!--v this should be German-->
    <div class="panel-body">
        <label class="control-label" translate="DESCRIPTION" translate-values="{ p0: someParameter }"></label>
        [...]
    </div>
    <!--^ this should be German-->
</div>
```

Also I need [variable replacement](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement) in the translation mechanism, as it is working with angular-translate so far

So far I could not find an elegant solution for this requirements.
Thanks for any help, tips or alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a custom asynchronous loader as describe [here](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Asynchronous-loading).

You could set `data` below by combining languages.

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.useLoader('customLoader', {
     // if you have some custom properties, go for it!
  });
});

app.factory('customLoader', function ($http, $q) {
    // return loaderFn
    return function (options) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // do something with $http, $q and key to load localization files

        var data = {
            'TEXT': 'Fooooo'
        };

        return deferred.resolve(data);
        // or
        return deferred.reject(options.key);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $translatePartialLoader with custom template url providing function:

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
  urlTemplate: function(part, lang) {
    if (part.indexOf('json') > -1) {
      return 'translations/' + part;
    }
    return 'translations/' + part + '_' + lang + '.json';
  }
});
```

Load content that needs to be translated according to $translate.use using

```
$translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('content');
```

This way content_lang.json will be loaded according to user language preference. For content that has fixed language load the exact file

```
$translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('fixed_de.json');
```

This file fill be loaded always ignoring user language choice.